# Python Wordcloud.fit_words() doesnt seem to work, what did i do wrong

Tags: python, word-cloud

so in trying to make a wordcloud of the 200 most frequent words in a textfile and top200words is a dict where the key is the words as a string and the value is an int

i've tried giving the .fit_words method a list of tuples as an argument but that didnt work aswell

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
top200words = dict(sorted(wordFreqDict.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True[:200])

wordcloud = WordCloud(colormap='prism',background_color='white')
wordcloud = WordCloud.fit_words(top200words)
wordcloud = WordCloud.to_file('prideandprejudicewordcloud.png')
```

error msg:

wordcloud = WordCloud.fit_words(top200words)
TypeError: WordCloud.fit_words() missing 1 required positional argument: 'frequencies'

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know what `WordCloud` (the class in your code, not the general concept) does?

Comment: im so sorry, forgot to include that

Comment: Adding the import doesn't really answer gspr's question. Could you add more context?